# How do I programmatically validate reCaptcha?

Tags: captcha

In Drupal 7, I use the [Commerce_Checkout_Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_redirect) module which uses custom validation functions. It uses the following code.

```
// Use the username as order email.
// Email validation for the username form element
if (variable_get('commerce_checkout_redirect_username_as_order_email', FALSE)) {
  $form['name']['#title'] = t('Email');
  $form['actions']['continue_button']['#limit_validation_errors'] = array(array('name'));
  $form['actions']['continue_button']['#validate'][] = 'commerce_checkout_redirect_username_as_order_email_form_validate';
}
```

The validation function is the following.

```
function commerce_checkout_redirect_username_as_order_email_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {...}
```

The form ID is *user_login*, the reCaptcha is enabled for this form and it is shown, but it is ignored by the validation process when users submit the form.

How can I "force" the validation of the reCaptcha inside a custom validation function?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself. The only thing i had to do is to add in *#limit_validation_errors* element another array with **captcha_response**.
So the right syntax is

```
$form['actions']['continue_button']['#limit_validation_errors'] = array(array('name'),array('captcha_response'));
```